# How can i specify multiple key columns in MySQL memcache plugin?

Tags: mysql, configuration, memcached, composite-key

After i configured and tried and have working the memcache plugin for MySQL, i've been unsuccesfully trying to add a namespace from a table with composite primary key. There is the example:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
`key` VARCHAR(3),
`key2` VARCHAR(3),
`value1` varchar(1024),
`value2` varchar(1024),
PRIMARY KEY (`key`,`key2`)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

And the row in the innodb_memcache.containers:

```
INSERT INTO innodb_memcache.containers (name, db_schema, db_table, key_columns, value_columns, flags, cas_column, expire_time_column, unique_idx_name_on_key) VALUES('test', 'kv_data', 'test', 'key|key2', 'value1|value2', '0', '0', '0', 'PRIMARY');
```

After that, if i do a set in memcache interface:

```
set @@test.hello|world 0 0 11
hello|world
```

The response from memcache is:

```
NOT_FOUND
```

Also, if i do a manual insert in the table, and do a get:

```
get @@test.val1|val2
```

The answer is END, as if the item does not exists in the database. This behaviour does not happen with single column primary keys.

Has anyone been able to configure succesfully memcache for this use case? I cannot find in the documentation anything related to composite primary keys, and also i don't think the name "key_columns" in containers table is a transcription error.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is late, but Innodb Memcached is not very well documented. So, I hope this will benefit someone.

In order to SET or GET you use @@ + the table name (from innodb_memcache.containers.name) + . (DOT) + key (from innodb_memcache.containers.key_columns).

In your case, for SET:

```
set @@test.EXAMPLE 0 0 11
hello|world
```

And for GET:

```
get @@test.EXAMPLE
```